# converting json in string to well json format

Tags: python, json

four sets of data convert to difference format of json `1-2=3.4=0` `6-7=8=0` `10-11=12=13` `14-15=16=0`

```
`1-2=3.4=0`  `6-7=8=0`    `10-11=12=13`
a:, "1-2"    a:,"6-7"     a:,"10-11" 
b:, "3.4"    b:,"8"       b:,"12"
c:, "0"      c:,"0"       c:,"13"
```

**raw data**

```
x = {'OUT': '091309@@@;1-2=3.4=0;6-7=8=0;10-11=12=13;14-15=16=0'}
```

**python code**

```
import json
x = json.dumps(x)
tmp = json.loads(x)
print(tmp.keys())
```

**retrieve keys**

```
tmp['OUT']

'091309@@@;1-2=3.4=0;6-7=8=0;10-11=12=13;14-15=16=0'
```

**expected result**

```
x = {'OUT':"091309@@@{'a': '1-2','b': '3.4','c': '0'},{'a': '6-7','b': '8','c': '0'},{'a': '10-11','b': '12','c': '13'},{'a': '14-15','b': '16','c': '0'}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `regex`

```py
import re
import json

x = {'OUT': '091309@@@;1-2=3.4=0;6-7=8=0;10-11=12=13;14-15=16=0'}

parsed_data = re.findall(r'([\d.]+-[\d.]+)=([\d.]+)=([\d.]+)', x['OUT'])

x['OUT'] = x['OUT'].split(';')[0] + ','.join(str(dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], i))) for i in parsed_data)

x
```

```
{'OUT': "091309@@@{'a': '1-2', 'b': '3.4', 'c': '0'},{'a': '6-7', 'b': '8', 'c': '0'},{'a': '10-11', 'b': '12', 'c': '13'},{'a': '14-15', 'b': '16', 'c': '0'}"}
```

Details of the regex found [here](https://regex101.com/r/zgLFtl/2)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here's one way to convert raw data to the expected result:

```
x['OUT'] = x['OUT'].split(';')[0] + ','.join(
    str(dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], i.split('=')))) for i in x['OUT'].split(';')[1:])
```